# Is there any way to monitor a MySQL db and check what has changed?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to understand the schema of woocommerce. It would be quite easy by monitoring the UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE query in a short time of period. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: wpactivitylog has a option for that.

Comment: NinjaFirewall is claiming to do that. You might have some luck checking their source code.